# Python, self['Location']?

Tags: python

In **django.http.response.py**, I found `self['Location']`:

```
class HttpResponseRedirectBase(HttpResponse):
    allowed_schemes = ['http', 'https', 'ftp']

    def __init__(self, redirect_to, *args, **kwargs):
        super(HttpResponseRedirectBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self['Location'] = iri_to_uri(redirect_to)
        parsed = urlparse(force_text(redirect_to))
        if parsed.scheme and parsed.scheme not in self.allowed_schemes:
            raise DisallowedRedirect("Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '%s'" % parsed.scheme)

url = property(lambda self: self['Location'])
```

What do the two `self['Location']` mean? Why can `self` be used like a `dict`.

Comment: A `dict` is merely an object implementing the correct methods for `[]` access. Any object can do that.

Comment: I say the `self['Location']` usage like a `dict`, because I don't know the attribute `__getitem__` before this. Now, I know it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HTTPResponse` class implements the `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`) magic method, which makes it possible to use the syntax `response['Header']` to [get the HTTP headers (and set, delete them)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields).

`HttpResponseRedirectBase` inherits this behaviour from `HTTPResponse`.

Comment: Thank you for letting me learn `__getitem__` (and `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`) in python.